# Concatenar string no meio de outra usando loop de array

Tags: php

Minha ideia é criar uma função em que irei passar um array como parâmetro com o formato

```
array("c_digo"=>$cod,"nome"=>$nomecompleto)
```

E criar um loop com este array para que ele crie os fields_attributes igual nesta string abaixo. atualmente estou criando na mao, quero fazer dinamicamente com o array. espero que tenha consigo explicar, qualquer duvida me perguntem

```
$queryObj = [
                'query' => 
                'mutation {
                  createCard(
                    input: {
                      pipe_id: '.$pipeid.'
                      fields_attributes: [{
                        field_id: "c_digo",
                        field_value: "'.$cod.'"
                      }{
                          field_id: "nome",
                          field_value: "'.$nomecompleto.'"
                      } {
                          field_id: "email",
                          field_value: "'.$email.'"
                      } {
                          field_id: "telefone",
                          field_value: "'.$telefone.'"
                      }]
                    }
                  ) {
                    card {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                }'
            ];
            $query = json_encode($queryObj);
```

Função pretendida

```
      public function createcard($array){
    // exemplo de array recebido: array("c_digo"=>$cod,"nome"=>$nomecompleto)
    // Create query object
//    deve criar esse queryobj já com os campos vindos do array ( atualmente ele ta preenchido manualmente)
    $queryObj = [
      'query' =>
        'mutation {
                  createCard(
                    input: {
                      pipe_id: '.$pipeid.'
                      fields_attributes: [{
                        field_id: "c_digo",
                        field_value: "'.$cod.'"
                      }{
                          field_id: "nome",
                          field_value: "'.$nomecompleto.'"
                      }]
                    }
                  ) {
                    card {
                      id
                    }
                  }
                }'
    ];

    $query = json_encode($queryObj);
//    deve retornar esta variavel $query


  }
```

Comment: arrays compostos?

Comment: É, não ficou muito claro não. Por quê não dá um exemplo de entrada que a função iria receber e qual a saída que ela deverá gerar? Talvez assim ficará mais fácil de entender.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss adicionei

Comment: cara, não entendi ainda, vc quer criar essa array dentro do loop?

Comment: Quero que o array se transforme nessa string, se o array tiver 3 elementos terei 3 fields_attributes e assim por diante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso que você quer:

```
function createcard($array){

    // coloquei esse valor pois ele não estava identificado no seu código
    $pipeid = 12334; // altere depois

    $queryObj = array();
    $string  = "mutation {createCard(input: { pipe_id: '$pipeid', fields_attributes: [";
    foreach($array as $key => $dados){
        $string .= "{field_id: '".$key."',";
        $string .= "field_value: '".$dados."'},";
    }
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
    $string .= "]}){card {id}}}";
    $queryObj['query'] = $string;
    return json_encode($queryObj);
}

$array = array("c_digo"=>"123","nome"=>"Igor Oliveira");

echo createcard($array);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado

Comment: @IgorOliveira valeu!

Comment: poderia me explicar oque o substr faz?

Comment: @IgorOliveira ele retira a ultima virgula que é criada no loop.

Comment: Essa linha `$string .= "field_value: '".$dados."'},";` cria uma vírgula no final. Com o substr eu retiro a ultima virgula criada.

Comment: @IgorOliveira você quer que eu faça alguma alteração?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, não precisa alterar, ja estou usando

Comment: @IgorOliveira tranquilo! =)